# How can I group by a field by a condition of that specific field?

Tags: sql, ms-access

My table has this values:

```
SommaDiImporto | codice_ordine_data
828,13         | 003644260517,003573190517,003740260517,003693230517
804,73         | 003644260517,003573190517,003740260517,003693230517
357,86         | 003644260517,003573190517,003740260517,003693230517
1727,82        | 003644260517,003573190517,003740260517,003693230517
200,69         | 003644260520,003573190520,003740260520,003693230520
0              | 003644260520,003573190520,003740260520,003693230520
600,58         | 003644260520,003573190520,003740260520,003693230520
123,47         | 003644260520,003573190520,003740260520,003693230520
```

The second field has the first four rows with the same values and the last four rows with same values too.
The query that I realized should return me this records:

```
SommaDiImporto | codice_ordine_data
3718,54        | 003644260517,003573190517,003740260517,003693230517
924,74         | 003644260520,003573190520,003740260520,003693230520
```

And this is what I expect:

```
SommaDiImporto | codice_ordine_data
3718,54        | 003644260517,003573190517,003740260517,003693230517
0              | 003644260520,003573190520,003740260520,003693230520
```

The first field of the last row should return 0 because in that grouped list there is at least a record setted to 0.

This is the query I realized:

```
SELECT SUM(IIF(TIMBRATURE.importo = 0, 0, TIMBRATURE.importo)) AS SommaDiImporto, TIMBRATURE.codice_ordine_data
FROM TIMBRATURE
GROUP BY TIMBRATURE.codice_ordine_data;
```

How I have to modify my query to return the desired result?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For values without NULL:

```
SELECT IIF(MIN(TIMBRATURE.importo) = 0, 0, SUM(TIMBRATURE.importo)) AS SommaDiImporto, TIMBRATURE.codice_ordine_data
FROM TIMBRATURE
GROUP BY TIMBRATURE.codice_ordine_data;
```

For values with NULL:

```
SELECT IIF(MIN(ISNULL(TIMBRATURE.importo, 0)) = 0, 0, SUM(TIMBRATURE.importo)) AS SommaDiImporto, TIMBRATURE.codice_ordine_data
FROM TIMBRATURE
GROUP BY TIMBRATURE.codice_ordine_data;
```

Try if this works!

Note: The function `ISNULL` depends on the database. This [article](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp) may help to find the exact function that should be used.

Comment: There is a little syntax error. Must be `IIf`instead of `If`. Many thanks!!

Comment: Edited! Thanks!
Sorry - tried the query on MySQL db so used IF !!

Comment: I need to set "SommaDiImporto" to 0 also for each value of the field "importo" that is NULL.
I edited the query like this:
`SELECT IIf(MIN(TIMBRATURE.importo)=0 OR MIN(TIMBRATURE.importo) Is Null,0,SUM(TIMBRATURE.importo)) AS SommaDiImporto, TIMBRATURE.codice_ordine_data
FROM TIMBRATURE
GROUP BY TIMBRATURE.codice_ordine_data;`
But still not work. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @FrancescoEsposto - I have edited the answer to take care of NULL values. Please give it a try!

Also, please if you can tell which Database you're using, I can give you the exact query.